# Drupal adding external links to custom menus

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to add a custom menu to Drupal 7 but it seems that I am not able to handle external links in hook_menu as they don't get inserted into the database. When I change the implementation to use menu_link_save, internal menu items don't get saved in the menu route table so they don't show up. Is there a way to implement a custom menu that will be displayed in the footer that contains both normal menu items and links to external websites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hook_menu()` is really only for internal paths by design and as such external paths don't belong in the `menu_router` table. There is a little trick you can do to make internal paths that you define immediately redirect to the external site, using [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto) as your page callback:

```
$items['my_internal_path'] = array(
  'title' => 'Title',
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
  'page arguments' => array('http://external-site.com/')
);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I apologize for not giving you the correct answer award back in 2011. This solution worked well then and continues to do so now even though there have been significant changes to Drupal in that time.

Comment: @MatthewPurdon No apology necessary :) Drupal 7 is as far as this one goes though, come Drupal 8 I don't think this method will work

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, atleast not now.

You can add external items like this

```
$items['http://facebook.com/'] = array(
  'title' => t('Facebook'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'menu_name' => 'menu-footer'
);
```

Comment: Thit is not true to what? Please be more specific.